# Python - open a file

Tags: python

I am reading a file csv with 900 rows and 600 columns with one of this methods:

1. df = pd.read_csv('filename',engine='python')
2. f = open(r'filename','r')

and everything is fine.

I am trying to read a file with the same path, the same folder, with half a million rows and 7 columns ,but I am getting an error:

> [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'filename.csv'

I don't know why, and I can't believe that python can't read a file with a half of millions rows.

Please help me understand why and finding a solution

Comment: That has nothing to do with the size. File size doesn't affect `open`. You're blaming the wrong thing.

Comment: It's likely not a valid filepath that you are using. Try giving the absolute (entire) path to the file